# Loading Google Maps in jQuery tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, tabs, rendering

I have issues loading a Google Map into a jQuery tab. I tried every single solution from the internet, using suggestions from here: 
[Google Maps V3 not loading with jQuery tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733488/google-maps-v3-not-loading-with-jquery-tabs)

[Problems with Google Maps API v3 + jQuery UI Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428178/problems-with-google-maps-api-v3-jquery-ui-tabs)

http://www.digitalwks.com/blogs/diogo-raminhos/google-maps-v3-and-jquery-tabs-jquery-tabs-google-maps-bug/

[Google Maps and jQuery Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014156/google-maps-and-jquery-tabs)

And so on...

But none of them worked, either I'm too noob to use them and I have no idea how to add them or are not working.

This is how the tabs are shown:

```
<div class="tabprice">

    <ul class="tabnavig">      
      <?php if ( $gmap_active ) { ?>
          <li><a href="#block2"><span class="big"><?php _e('Map', 'anuncios') ?></span></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>

<?php if ( $gmap_active ) { ?>

    <!-- tab 2 -->
    <div id="block2">

        <div class="clr"></div>

            <div class="singletab">

                <?php include_once ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/sidebar-gmap.php' ); ?>

            </div><!-- /singletab -->

    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

And here is the content of sidebar-gmap.php

http://pastebin.com/H3i4J8EN

Please guys, I beg you, help me !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of [one of the blogposts you refered](http://www.digitalwks.com/blogs/diogo-raminhos/google-maps-v3-and-jquery-tabs-jquery-tabs-google-maps-bug/).

**For other persons with the same problem: The problem in here relies on the fact that you need to trigger the resize event when your show animation ends.**

**You can do that by calling** `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` **on your show animation end callback.**

So, in your case (for the link [you sended](http://anuncios.media-zone.info/anuncios/pioneer-cdj2000/)) you need to:

**Edit the following file:**

> /wp-content/themes/anuncios/includes/js/theme-scripts.js

**And replace this:**

```
/* Tab Control home main */
jQuery(function($) {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabcontrol > div');
    tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();
    $('div.tabcontrol ul.tabnavig a').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide();
        tabContainers.filter(this.hash).fadeIn(100);
        $('div.tabcontrol ul.tabnavig a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

**With this:**

```
/* Tab Control home main */
jQuery(function($) {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabcontrol > div');
    tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();
    $('div.tabcontrol ul.tabnavig a').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide();
        tabContainers.filter(this.hash).fadeIn(100, function(){
            if(map != undefined && map != null)
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });
        $('div.tabcontrol ul.tabnavig a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

---

**Part 2**

Find the following code:

```
$(tabs).click(function() {
    // hide all tabs
    $(tabContainers).hide().filter(this.hash).fadeIn(500);
    $(tabs).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

And replace it with

```
$(tabs).click(function() {
    // hide all tabs
    $(tabContainers).hide().filter(this.hash).fadeIn(500, function(){
        if(map != undefined && map != null)
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
    $(tabs).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

And your bug will be fixed, this time I downloaded and tested it locally so I'm 100% sure it will work.

Comment: Wow, thank you my friend. Obrigado ! I appreciate your help. I edited that part, but as you can see, nothing has been changed. I still left the change you proposed me in that file, but the problem persists.

Comment: Hey I just updated my answer, check out the **Part 2**, i tested it locally and It will work ;)

Comment: OMG, it's really works. Thank you so much man. Sadly, you don't have any "Buy me a beer" button on your websites, because for sure you deserve it. Amazing !

Answer (score 3):

Google map need a visible and fixed canvas (div) to calculate a width and height of map in order to show it correctly. If you hide your div before, you must show it first then trigger map resize `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` .

In your case, call resize in calculate() function seems ideal

```
function codeAddress() {
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

Comment: I have seen that in the links I added in my question. I tried adding that but didn't worked. Can you give me please more information ? Thanks for reply btw.

Comment: Can you give me your url so I can take a look? Or just make some working example on jsfiddle...

Comment: Hey Trinh, here is the link: http://pastebin.com/XsDAGhtG  I added it here because I don't want it crawled by google.  Also, I included the 2 php files in my question above. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have a working copy of google maps in jquery tabs here http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/529/

I used some of the code from your sources that you listed above. This is the code that does it. the other stuff is just map stuff not too important

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").css({'visibility':'hidden'  , 'position':'absolute'});
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 
    $(".tab_content:first").css({'visibility':'visible' , 'position':'static'}); 

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active"); 
        $(".tab_content").css({'visibility':'hidden' , 'position':'absolute'}); 
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
        $(activeTab).css({'visibility':'visible'  , 'position':'static'});
        return false;
    });
});​
```

keep in mind that this works only with the div tags i've shown in jsfiddle since I check the `id` and `class` tags in the divs to activate a tab. I just change the visibility of the div to hidden or visible basically.

hope this helps you out.

Comment: Oh boy....this one looks amazing. I'm trying to implement it in my code but at this moment I'm getting just a blank page instead of the map. I can't change it completely as in your code but still playing with the code. What exactly you used to fix that issue ? Markers ? google.maps.event.addListener ?